# buggy unicode when using it in python

Tags: python, encoding, base64, ascii

i was trying to decode and encode with base 64 message. here is code i used:

```py
@bot.command()
async def base64(ctx, arg1, *, arg):
  if arg1 == "encode":
    var1 = arg1.encode("latin-1")
    var2 = b64.b64encode(var1)
    var3 = var2.decode("latin-1")
    await ctx.send(f"{var3}")
  elif arg1 == "decode":
    var1 = arg1
    var2 = var1.encode("latin-1")
    var3 = b64.b64decode(var2)
    var4 = var3.decode("latin-1")
    await ctx.send(f"{var3}")
  else:
    return
```

depending what i use i get errors like : `incorrect padding` (when just sending message without adding "==") or `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` - when i try to add 8 "=" like said in https://gist.github.com/perrygeo/ee7c65bb1541ff6ac770 . when finally i made it as good as it outputted anything - it shown another message than expected (encoded was `Hello world!!!` and i got `b'u\xe7(u'`) - this worked but i had encoding setted to `utf-8` - for me both "binary" and "latin-1" show error with bugged padding. no way for that?

Was trying both with commands : `$base64 decode SGVsbG8gd29ybGQhISE==` and `$base64 decode SGVsbG8gd29ybGQhISE=` and `$base64 decode SGVsbG8gd29ybGQhISE==` as input

Comment: Base 64 should all be ASCII, so the encoding after that should be irrelevant because ASCII is a subset of both Latin-1 and UTF-8.

Comment: It makes no sense to decode as latin-1 after encoding as b64

Comment: `SGVsbG8gd29ybGQhISE=` decodes to `b'Hello world!!!'`  None of the values that you have provided can possibly decode to `b'u\xe7(u'`.  If you are try to decode the bytes that you get from calling `b64decode` then (1) You need to be sure the bytes are encoded text and not binary data like images (2) You need to know the encoding used to encode the text originally, or use a package that will guess the original encoding.

Comment: Im not trying to decode image

Comment: Edit -> changed encoding to ascii and renamed variables (arg1 to arg). Now outputs messages like b'message'. No way to remove these added characters?